# TortoiseHg and TortoiseGit context menu confilct

Tags: tortoisehg, tortoisegit

I am using WindowsXP and have installed TortoiseHg(Ver 2.2.1 with mercurial 2.0.1) and TortoiseGit(1.7.6.0) git version 1.7.8.msysgit.0

When I right click on the desktop, my TortoiseHg's ICON seems to be squeezed away by the TortoiseGit's ICONS

[image: My right click menu context after installing TortoiseHg and TortoiseGit]

Is there any solution?

Best Regards,
Sheng Yun

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with TortoiseGit?

Comment: because it happend after I install TortoiseGit, and if I uninstall TortoiseGit, everything works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's known problem
2. It's old (at least 2-releases) problem
3. It isn't TorroiseGit-specific, but Tortoise* (I got it with TortoiseSVN)
4. There aren't solution at this time (except unisntall TortoiseGit and use pure hg + hg-git)

Comment: Is this a known problem only on Windows XP (which I haven't used in years)? I don't have any problems on Windows 7 with TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHg. Perhaps they've stopped supporting XP since it's over 10 years old now?

Comment: @CodyGray - [Stefan wrote](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2872518) about **Win7** problem in early November 2011. Maybe Win7-fix broke XP (I have none workplaces with Win7 now, can speak only for XP)